# Cant hide progress bar when using binding

Tags: java, android, binding

I know there are similar questions but none of their solutions worked for me.

I have an activity with bunch of textviews, that i bind a model on. Besides this model there is a list of different data. As soon as the list is loaded, i am trying to hide a ProgressBar. But nothings seem to be working, i have tried View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE. I have even tried running the code on a different thread.

I'm guessing the binding is preventing me from changing the visibility. Does anybody have some information on this?

Edit: code below:

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/userStatuses_spinner"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="80dp" />

spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.userStatuses_spinner);

spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: post your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line because in data binding not need to find id.

```
spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.userStatuses_spinner);
```

Getting progress bar from xml and set visibility like this:

```
binding.userStatusesSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

where binding is your xml binding view.